# E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**FIXED**
 **update Firebase to 9.0.2**

After I have upgraded firebase to 9.0.0.
(Now to 9.0.1)

I'm trying to use CUSTOM AUTHENTICATION in firebase auth
This error is coming n my App crashes after it without any other sort of errors we get..

```
E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rana.sahaj.myyu-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.rana.sahaj.myyu-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Using the latest Android Studio 2.1.1

Google Play services ,rev 30

n i didnt found any revelant answer to this problem

Comment: *firebaser here* We're investigating an issue with Firebase Authentication that might cause this behavior. Monitor the associated [Firebase Authentication status page](http://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/16001) for the latest updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update to **9.0.2** it will resolve all the problems.

Also update **Google Repository** and **Google Play Services**, there is an update for them too.. n it will work like charm.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me

Comment: also update your google play services there is a new update

Answer (score 1):

Please update **firebase** to **9.4.0**

Comment: dude this Doesn't WORK

Answer (score 0):

Please update google repository then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following steps:

1. That you have the very latest version of play services referenced in  gradle (9.0.2 as at the time of posting)
2. That your Google repository is updated.
3. That you have signed into the play store on your test device.
4. That you have updated play services on your test devices to the latest possible version

Comment: Alright, just putting it out there for any other person that may face the issue @SahajRana

Answer (score 0):

enble email/password from your firebase dashboard